# Cache common blocks of HTML on each page

Tags: html, caching

We have a common navigation bar on each page.

How would you cache this so it is not loaded on every page?

Answer (score 1):

You could load it using AJAX in the `onload` event of each page and append it in the respective navigation container on your page.

As long as the request to the menu stays static, the browser should be able to cache the response. Hence, you have basically cached your menu on the client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content into a variable inside a javascript file navigation.js

```
nav_bar = "....."
```

Then include this `navigation.js` on each page and insert the content in the current page via JavaScript.